# Position of a record change to Last Position after updation. + PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

When i m updating a record in my DB, the position of the Particular record is 
changed to last.

My question is : - 
Is there any way to retain the position
of the updated record in the DB.

Can any body Please help me on this.

Thanks 
Regards,
Binaya

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to influence the physical positioning of rows in PostgreSQL and the order in which they are returned also depends on the query plan, using index or table scan and the way joins are performed. You must use ORDER BY to get rows in a specific order.

Comment: Thanks Eelke, for ur suggetion